# HTTPS configuration in Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, airflow-webserver

I am new to devops. I have a scenario, where i need to install Airflow and open https to access globally.
Below are the  steps i done.

1. Created EC2 and installed Airflow
2. Install Httpd and opened 443 port and restarted httpd
3. Generated ssl certification internally with in server and configured .crt and .key file.

Problem: The htts:// is crossed and showing the certification is not valid, i believe it's a certification issue, can any one help on this to fix.

Note: i don't like to purchase any certification from third party. And my EC2 machine can be restarted monthly once for maintenance(public IP might be changed). I tried, Amazon certification manager and load balancer and looks it's costing.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWfez.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Generated ssl certification internally with in server and configured .crt and .key file.

By this do you mean you created a self signed certificate? If yes, then usually self signed certificates do give that warning.

Amazon certificate manager is free service and can be assigned with few AWS services. See if your website can be hosted using any particular service that ACM supports.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, the certification is self signed.

Comment: Yep. With self-signed you do get that error. If you do not want to spend money, you can consider using zero-ssl or certbot for free ssl. You need to keep renewing them every quarter or something. Do check if it meets your needs.

Apart from this, also check if your ssl is properly configured in your server